# Automatic Form Generation

Tags: html, forms

I am a data scientist, tasked with creating forms for user inputs to computations. These inputs include date ranges, integers, etc. Every computation describes its necessary and optional inputs. I would like to automatically turn a computation description into an HTML form, including (server side) validation of user entries. For a toy example, consider

Computation 1: Divide a by b
Description: Divide two integers!
a: int
b: int
Result: a/b

This should be turned into an HTML form asking for a, b, and the description. This form does not need to be pretty, but should look presentable. There are many graphical form building tools out there, is there also a tool allowing programmatic form building? Is there even an open source tool? Since I am not a frontend developer I would prefer to use such a tool instead of developing my own logic. I would also like to keep the validation logic on the server side (here: b!=0), necessitating the possibility to programmatically talk to the form in some way.

On a higher level, is this even the right way to go about creating UIs for computations defining their own inputs, with short computation times?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=automated+form+creation+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.